# What's the difference between nan, NaN and NAN

Tags: python, numpy, nan

In numpy there are `nan`, `NaN` and `NAN`. What's the sense of having all three, do they differ or any of these can be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
>>> numpy.nan is numpy.NaN is numpy.NAN
True
```

It's just convenient. They're exactly the same.

Answer (score 9):

Different operating systems and programming languages may have different string representations of NaN:

```
 nan  
 NaN  
 NaN%  
 NAN  
 NaNQ  
 NaNS  
 qNaN  
 sNaN
 1.#SNAN
 1.#QNAN  
 -1.#IND
```

I think having all three is just a convenience. They are the same.

```
>>> np.nan
nan
>>> np.NaN
nan
>>> np.NAN
nan
>>>
```