# Changing 9.90000000e+01 to numpy nans

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a data set which comprises of  9.90000000e+01 however, I would like to change them to nans. How would I go about doing this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing numpy arrays containing NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10710328/608639) and maybe [What's the difference between nan, NaN and NAN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17825707/608639). You might also be interested in [Does the np.nan in numpy array occupy memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44624404/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataset is called `arr`, use a mask like this:

```
arr[arr==99] = np.nan
```

For example:

```
>>> arr = np.array([9.90000000e+01,9.90000000e+02,9.90000000e+01])
>>> arr
array([ 99., 990.,  99.])

>>> arr[arr==99] = np.nan
>>> arr
array([ nan, 990.,  nan])
```

Comment: Thanks sacul I was forgetting that for assignments I needed the ==