# Why the replace method of pandas does not work with None as value?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,"NAN",3], "b": ["NAN",5,"NAN"], "c": ["NAN",8,9]})

     a    b    c
0    1  NAN  NAN
1  NAN    5    8
2    3  NAN    9
```

When I try to preform a regular `replace` I get incorrect results:

```
df = df.replace('NAN', None)

   a    b    c
0  1  NAN  NAN
1  1    5    8
2  3    5    9
```

However, when I have the values as lists it works as expected:

```
df = df.replace(['NAN'], [None])

    a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  5.0  8.0
2  3.0  NaN  9.0
```

Can you please explain why the behavior is different in these two cases?

PS: pandas version is 1.0.3.

Comment: What if you try  `df = df.replace(['NAN'], None)` ?

Comment: When you use `value=None`, `replace` handles it as the default (i.e. no parameter)

Comment: @Adrien, same as `df = df.replace('NAN', None)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was answered [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19998):

`df.replace("NAN", None)` is equivalent to `df.replace("NAN", None, method='pad')` if you look into the source code.

Both `df.replace({"NAN": None})` and `df.replace("NAN", np.nan)` give you what you want

Comment: Small typo: it is `df.replace({"NAN": None})` not `df.replace({"NAN", None})`. +1

Comment: @Daniel Wyatt, thank you for your reply! Another useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825707/whats-the-difference-between-nan-nan-and-nan